# bird that might be a young one that didn't fledge happily

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

Can anyone identify this bird - located in Massachusetts[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. For identification questions please include an estimate of the size, what part of Massachusetts, and include any behavioral, habitat (e.g. types of plants), or other details that you noticed. In addition, if possible clearer pictures from multiple angles would be very helpful. Please [edit] your post to include as much of that information as possible. Also, what do you mean by "didn't fledge happily"? ——— Please also take the [tour] and go through the [help] starting with [ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to be sure without clearer pictures, but my best guess would be a female (and/or immature) [Brown-headed cowbird](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Brown-headed_Cowbird/id).

This is based on the heavy conical beak, my guess at the size, the overall grey-brown coloration, dark eye, dark beak, dark legs, and the faint suggestion of a line behind the eye. In addition, this is a common species in many parts of Massachusetts.

If you have seen these cowbirds (the males are quite distinctive) in your area that would support this idea.

[image: female brown-headed cow bird]
Public domain image from [USGS](https://www.usgs.gov/media/images/female-brown-headed-cow-bird).

Comment: Cowbirds do not raise their own young, they lay their eggs in other birds nests . The cowbird young are generally larger then and push out the original young. It could be the adoptive parents have abandoned this one as it seems big enough to be on its own .

Comment: Yes, does that have something to do with my answer?

Comment: Looks like a young Cowbird to me, for the same reasons that tyersome gave.  Young Cowbirds, like young Starlings, are pretty bland and unmarked.  The short neck and big round head also point in that direction.

Comment: Another similarity that could be added to your reasoning is the culmen/dorsal ridge of the upper mandible (The upper prong of the mandible is embedded into the forehead) that looks quite similar when enlarging the OP's picture.